# Entity Framework returning empty values

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to return a list from my WCF service to the client.

I am using Entity Framework to query against my database

I have the following code in my Entity Framework library :

```
public List<Users> getUsersByLastName(string pLastName)
{
    using (var context = new AMTEntitiesContainer())
    {
        var users = context.Users
                           .Where((c) => c.LastName.Contains(pLastName))
                           .ToList();
        return users;
    }
}
```

This is how I am capturing the result in my WCF and returning it :

```
public List<wcfUser> getUsersByLastName(string pLastName)
{
    UserMethods userMethods = new UserMethods();
    List<Users> usersList = userMethods.getUsersByLastName(pLastName);
    List<wcfUser> usersListForClient = new List<wcfUser>();
    wcfUser usersForClient = new wcfUser();
    foreach (Users u in usersList)
    {
        usersForClient = new wcfUser();
        TranslateServerUserToClientUser(u, usersForClient);
        usersListForClient.Add(usersForClient);
    }
    return usersListForClient;
}
```

The thing is, for some reason the usersList is always empty..why so?

I checked that the DB is not empty by throwing the same queries into LINQPad

Comment: Would you check your translator?

Comment: I double checked my translator but still..the list is not null..is empty :(

Comment: What im getting on the client when invoking this function is d:[]

Comment: I pass the value of "m" or also ""..I even hard coded so that when it will do .Contains("") instead of receiving the parameter..but still it responds d:[]

Comment: @MaG3Stican So if you put a breakpoint on `return usersListForClient;` it is filled with data? If so, try updating your service reference.

Comment: It has a list with .Count = 0

Comment: @MaG3Stican Than comment out `.Where((c) => c.LastName.Contains(pLastName))` and put a breakpoint on `return users;`. Verify that there are items returned.

Comment: it does return the full list of users when I take out the where..

Comment: So you known what the problem is now. Good luck.

Comment: I really dont know, what is wrong about doing .Where((c) => c.LastName.Contains("")

Comment: Only thing I can come up with is that all last names are null.

Comment: "{\"d\":[{\"__type\":\"wcfUser:#WebRoleUploadImages\",\"Age\":23,\"Birthday\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000+0000)\\/\",\"DateJoined\":null,\"DateLastLogin\":null,\"Email\":\"marquele9@hotmail.com\",\"Gender\":\"\",\"IdUser\":1,\"LastName\":\"marcos\",\"Name\":\"marcos echeverr\",\"Password\":\"\",\"ProfilePicture\":null,\"UserName\":\"marcos\"},{\"__type\":\"wcfUser:#WebRoleUploadImages\",\"Age\":23,\"Birthday\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000+0000)\\/\",\"DateJoined\":null,\"DateLastLogin\":null,\"Email\":\"marquele9@hotmail.com\",\"Gender\":\"\",\"IdUser\":2,\"LastName\":\"marcos2\",\"Name\":\"marcos

Comment: As you can see up here that is the result im getting when I return all the users in the database..there are two users, and each has a at least something on their last names..remember that I made c.LastName.Contains("") and it does not return a thing either..

Comment: That is the result after calling `TranslateServerUserToClientUser(u, usersForClient);` which could be setting `LastName` with te wrong value, otherwise it is impossible what you say.

Comment: Your problem is very weird. Have you tried using where clause with some other filter?

Comment: Found it : The problem is that the clientUser is not getting modified by the translate method, dont know why really. I followed every step and it is passing the data from my EF entity to the clientUser, but those changes to my clientUser are never happening after it goes out of the translation function scope O.O

Answer (score 1):

This solved it, apparently the DB is returning something weird but this captured it :

```
private AMTEntitiesContainer context = new AMTEntitiesContainer();

public IEnumerable<Users> getUsersByLastName(string pLastName)
{
    IQueryable<Users> results;

    results = (from m in context.Users
               where m.LastName.StartsWith(pLastName)
               select m);

    return results;
}
```